# How to make invisible react-google-recaptcha, Formik and yup work together?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup, invisible-recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

I'm trying to make invisible [react-google-recaptcha](https://github.com/dozoisch/react-google-recaptcha), [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/overview) and [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) to work together. The documentation says we should call `recaptchaRef.current.execute()` on form submission, but if we use Formik and yup together, it will trigger the submission logic only after all fields passed the validation schema.

Basically, we need to call the `execute` method, update the recaptcha value and submit the form with the same trigger event. My problem is exactly that: I'm having to use two events (one for the `execute` method and update the recaptcha + one to submit the form).

Check this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-mahavira-ont8z?file=/src/App.js

As you can see, the form is submitted only with the second click in the submit button...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Formik, there are some ways to do background work for your form's. This basically could be achieved with `handleChange` or `handleBlur` props being passed to the form component.

For instance, I am sure you would have other inputs in your form elements and not just a captcha (`if it's just a captcha in the form, then do let me know! - this can also be solved`)

So when you have other elements, you can ensure to use some of the Formik's API to handle the automatic trigger:

- [handleBlur](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#handleblur-e-any--void) event to trigger the ReCaptcha
- [isSubmitting](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#issubmitting-boolean) to control the submit button's state
- [setSubmitting](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setsubmitting-issubmitting-boolean--void) event to manipulate the button's state

As I see, there are a lot of ways to handle this through their API's: https://formik.org/docs/api/formik

The way I tried to achieve it is by adding a listener for `onBlur` on all fields and then checking if reCaptcha value is present or not. Based on that I trigger the execute the captcha and ensure to set the submitting value as true:

```
const handleBlur = (e) => {
  console.log("$$$$", props.isSubmitting);
  if (!props.values.recaptcha) {
    this._reCaptchaRef.current.execute();
    props.setSubmitting(true);
  }
  props.handleBlur(e);
};
```

Here is the CodeSandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-saha-qq7hg?file=/src/App.js

This shows the working model of handling `onBlur` of a field and triggering it in the background. If you notice, you can also disable and enable the submit button using `isSubmitting` and `setSubmitting`.

Also setting `validateOnChange={false}` and `validateOnBlur={false}`, because there is no need to validate on change or blur for captcha.

Pasting code here just in case for you to glance:

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";

import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";

const TEST_SITE_KEY = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI";

export default class MyForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
      recaptcha: yup.string().required(),
      name: yup.string().required(),
      address: yup.string().required()
    });
    this._initialValues = { recaptcha: "", name: "", address: "" };
    this._reCaptchaRef = createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        validationSchema={this._validationSchema}
        initialValues={this._initialValues}
        validateOnChange={false}
        validateOnBlur={false}
        onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
      >
        {(props) => {
          const handleBlur = (e) => {
            console.log("$$$$", props.isSubmitting);
            if (!props.values.recaptcha) {
              this._reCaptchaRef.current.execute();
              props.setSubmitting(true);
            }
            props.handleBlur(e);
          };

          return (
            <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
              <label>Name: </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={props.handleChange}
                value={props.values.name}
                name="name"
                onBlur={handleBlur}
              />
              <label>Address: </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={props.handleChange}
                value={props.values.address}
                name="address"
                onBlur={handleBlur}
              />
              <ReCAPTCHA
                ref={this._reCaptchaRef}
                sitekey={TEST_SITE_KEY}
                onChange={(value) => {
                  console.log("$$$$", props.isSubmitting, value);
                  props.setFieldValue("recaptcha", value);
                  props.setSubmitting(false);
                }}
                size="invisible"
              />
              <button type="submit" disabled={props.isSubmitting}>
                SUBMIT
              </button>

              {props.errors.name && <div>{props.errors.name}</div>}
            </form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer seems to be everything I need right now and yet, it simply just does not work for me. I'm using functional component and withFormik, but the basics are the same - I have handleBlur event, which uses the ref created by useRef() hook and calls _reCaptchaRef.current.execute(), but nothing happens. The request is not sent (I watch the network tab in dev tools) and ReCAPTCHA onChange never triggers. And I have no ide what is going on.

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb feel free to share the codesandbox if possible. Will check and provide info on anything I find there.

Comment: Here's my barebones example: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-benz-f2ovz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with the functional component. I recreated the same component as class based component and that works just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-architecture-r0gzj?file=/src/App.js (if you use testing key not the key it currently has)

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb I couldn't get the exact behaviour of this codesandbox. What are you exactly trying with button click?

Comment: I'm using button click as a replacement for a formfield onBlur/handleBlur. Just an outside trigger, which is supposed to trigger the .execute()

Comment: But can you provide an example that is not working with `handleBlur`? I can't seem to get the code you have added to handle the same.

Comment: Look it's not the handle blur that's the problem. the ref.current.execute() does not work.

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb change your `import { ReCAPTCHA } from "react-google-recaptcha";` to `import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";` in your [functional component](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-benz-f2ovz?file=/src/App.js) codesandbox and it's working